# PayPal HTTP 1.1 and PayPal HTML Form

Tags: paypal

Sorry if this sounds stupid, but after getting this mail.

> In a statement of 18 October 2011, we indicated that we would expand
>   the number of IP addresses for www.paypal.com to improve the
>   performance, scalability and availability of our website. In this
>   context, we will discontinue support for HTTP 1.0 from 7 October 2013.
>   Following this change , some of our dealers may have difficulty in
>   validating the retransmission of IPN ( Instant Payment Notification )
>   data or send PDT ( Payment Data Transfer ) to www.paypal.com and
>   ipnpb.paypal.com . This is the case when the IPN or PDT scripts using
>   HTTP 1.0 and does not include the header "Host : www.paypal.com " or "
>   Host: ipnpb.paypal.com " in the HTTP request .
>
> additional Information From October 7, 2013 , all applications
>   received will have the header "Host" in accordance with the HTTP 1.1
>   specification. This header was not required under HTTP 1.0 . IPN and
>   PDT scripts that use HTTP 1.0 may fail with the error " HTTP/1.0 400
>   Bad Request " type from 7 October 2013. Consequently, the IPN messages
>   can not be properly validated or PDT scripts will not retrieve
>   information about the transactions.
>
> Action required before October 7, 2013 Vendors must update their IPN
>   and / or PDT scripts to use the HTTP 1.1 and HTTP include the "Host"
>   header and protocol " Connection: close " in the script retransmission
>   IPN data.

Does this apply to the HTML Form Basics for Website Payments Standard , because from what i can tell it applies to scripts making remote calls. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't apply to Website Payments Standard buttons; it only applies to those who make - as you say - remote calls from a server to PayPal's server, such as with [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

Comment: Thanks a lot robert,i didn't want to report to my boss based on what i think. :)